# sidekiq true god.rb never runs my workers, where same command from terminal does?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, sidekiq, god

Running god.rb to start and monitor Sidekiq this does not work. Below my god config for sidekiq.

Running sidekiq -C /srv/books/current/config/sidekiq.yml manually from terminal on production does work fine, but not the sidekiq god.rb config anyone an idea why this could happen? Nothing much in the logs.

```
God.watch do |w|

  w.name = "sidekiq"
  w.interval = 30.seconds
  w.start = "cd #{ENV['RAILS_ROOT']}; sidekiq -C /srv/books/current/config/sidekiq.yml"
  w.stop = "cd #{ENV['RAILS_ROOT']}; exec sidekiqctl stop /srv/books/shared/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid"
  w.restart = "#{w.stop} && #{w.start}"
  w.start_grace = 10.seconds
  w.restart_grace = 10.seconds
  w.log = File.join(ENV['RAILS_ROOT'], 'log', 'sidekiq.log')

  # determine the state on startup
  w.transition(:init, {true => :up, false => :start}) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
    end
  end

  # determine when process has finished starting
  w.transition([:start, :restart], :up) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = true
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end

    # failsafe
    on.condition(:tries) do |c|
      c.times = 5
      c.transition = :start
      c.interval = 5.seconds
    end
  end

  # start if process is not running
  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
      c.running = false
    end
  end


  # Notifications
  # --------------------------------------
  w.transition(:up, :start) do |on|
    on.condition(:process_exits) do |p|
      p.notify = 'ect'
    end
  end


end
```

Comment: are RAILS_ENV/RAILS_ROOT set ?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing `RAILS_ROOT` definition. You use it in the script, but it's never defined. It probably works in the terminal because it's set there. But when god.rb runs it, you don't get the terminal environment, but a new clean one.

Try adding this to your god script:

```
w.env = { 'RAILS_ROOT' => "/srv/books/current",
          'RAILS_ENV' => "production" }
```

You can also just set it as a normal ruby variable as shown in [the example](http://godrb.com/#wiki-_config_files_are_ruby_code).

Comment: Have not tested this, I do soon have been absence for a while from stack. If it works I grant the right answer. I have in god.rb ENV['RAILS_ROOT']   = "/srv/books/current" god.rb includes my other .god config files in a /god subdir ( the separate services where the /config/god.rb is the main config file) note sure if this would yield the same